# Why is my if statement always evaluating to false within a switch statement?

Tags: bash, if-statement, switch-statement

My if statement always evaluates to false within my switch statement.  I tried using boolean variables and now just numerics and I get the same result.  The if statement isn't working.

```
#!/bin/bash

hidden=1

while true; do

    read -sn 1 input

    case $input in
        q ) 
                ;;
        n )     
                ;;
        h )     if ! [ $hidden ]; then  # hide video
                    echo "hidden (false): $hidden"
                    hidden=1
                else    # show video
                    echo "hidden (true): $hidden"
                    hidden=0
                fi
                ;;
        '' )    ;;
        \? );;  
    esac

done
exit 0
```

If I run it and press "h" a few times I get..

```
hidden (true): 1
hidden (true): 0
hidden (true): 0
hidden (true): 0
```

Why does my if statement always evaluate to false?

Comment: Thanks for including a MCVE. You could have made it even smaller by manually substituting out the values to pinpoint exactly where it goes wrong: `if [ 0 ]; then echo "Why is this true?"; fi`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[ $hidden ]` is equivalent to `[ -n $hidden ]` and checks if `$hidden` expands to a non-empty string; both `0` and `1` are non-empty strings and evaluate to true, so `! [ $hidden ]` is false.

Side note: if `$hidden` is actually an empty string, you'll get a syntax error; to prevent that, quote like this:

```
if ! [ "$hidden" ]; then
```

To do what I think you want, you have to use a different [conditional construct](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Conditional-Constructs):

```
if ! (( hidden )); then
```

This evaluates `hidden` in an [arithmetic context](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Arithmetic); a value of `0` is considered false, and non-zero is true. In an arithmetic context, you can skip the `$`, hence `hidden` instead of `$hidden`. Quoting isn't required either. Notice that `(( ))` is a Bash extension; if you want the same in POSIX sh, you have to use

```
if ! [ "$hidden" = 1 ]; then
```